# handle NaN in pyplot, python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some timelines including NaN's with pyplot (see sample code). The problem is, that when there's a NaN, pyplot doesn't draw a line between the points before and after the NaN. Is there any solution to change this behaviour?
I don't want to fill in any computed data points instead of the NaN. Deleting the NaN is not an option either, because that would result in the x- and y-lists having different lengths.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
y = [1, 2, 5, 4, 7, "nan", 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1]

plt.show(plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', linewidth = 0.5))
```

Thanks a lot,
Julian

Comment: Are your values really `"nan"` i.e a _string_? Or are they actually `NaN`?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar: The approach in the other thread is to fill the NaN gap with computed data points. That's what I don't want to do.

Comment: @DavidG: currently, it's really "nan", but I could change that to NaN easily if it helps to find an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're actually talking about `np.nan`, I frequently address this problem by:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
y = np.array([1, 2, 5, 4, 7, "nan", 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1], dtype=np.float64)

goods = ~np.isnan(y)

line = plt.plot(x[goods], y[goods], 'o-', linewidth = 0.5)
```

This way your `x` and `y` variables are unchanged, but the plot doesn't have gaps. Note here that I've:

- initalized `x` and `y` as arrays at the outset so that they can be indexed by the boolean array `goods`
- forced `y` to be a `np.float64` array (so that `'nan'` becomes a `np.nan`).

### Sidenote

If you really are talking about the string 'nan' (or some other string you want to exclude), you could do something like:

```
y = np.array([1, 2, 5, 4, 7, "nan", 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1])
goods = (y != "nan")
```

Note that in this case, I haven't forced `y` to be `float64`, and so it ends up being a `|S21`. However, matplotlib converts this to `float64` (take a look at `line[0].get_xydata()`) before plotting so in general it's probably simplest to apply the first approach. Otherwise, matplotlib might throw errors if there are other strings in `y` that can't be converted to `float64`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you prefer to not have to remove the "nan".  However, I know of no other way to get the line to connect (without interpolation, or filling the data somehow).  So, I suspect the easiest options might be to remove the "nan" from `y` and the corresponding index in `x`.

```
>>> del x[y.index("nan")]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

>>> y.remove("nan")
>>> y
[1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1]
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work for me, because I use the x list for different plots with different y lists.